# Restricting key creation for specific GCP Service account in specific project belonging to an organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have a requirement where I want to restrict certain service account from creating key (json/yaml file) but that restriction should only affect specific service account in a specific project which belongs to an organization.

I did go through the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-service-accounts?_ga=2.80122519.-1618589810.1615986014#disable_service_account_key_creation), but It did not match the requirement of restricting only certain service account rather than all service account in that particular organization.

Comment: Not possible for now. Can change in the futur but not ETA for that.

Comment: it's not possible

Comment: Just an update, I had created internal ticket on GCP project, and they opened up feature request on Google public issue tracker, following is the link if anyone wants to follow up on the same https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183809361

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only restrict key creation on project level.
Based on you configuration, in may be viable to restrict user's access to a Service Account - [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts?_ga=2.230519700.-943366271.1609237588&_gac=1.127219199.1614942003.Cj0KCQiAyoeCBhCTARIsAOfpKxijq33XiJ8KGlAFklnWRXTzqXTVlLqy2qWurWplfhNxZ2PfRAn0c6oaAgjqEALw_wcB#viewing-roles).
Another workaround would be to split your resources into smaller projects, so that they are easier to manage.

If you think that policy restricting key creation  for only selected service accounts should be available, you can file a Feature Request on [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187161&template=0).